# Escaped Slashes in String Literals

Tags: python

I am trying to escape a "/" within a dictionary.  This dict holds a number of urls.

This works correctly -

```
>>> url = "https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html"
>>> print url.replace('/','\\/') 
https:\/\/docs.python.org\/2\/reference\/expressions.html
```

but when I put the same pattern into my dict, I get a different result.  I am sure this has to do with string literals but I am not sure how to continue.

```
try:
    data["URL"] = url.replace('/','\\/')
```

returns:

```
"http:\\/\\/docs.python.org"
```

Comment: That's the string representation. Try printing it

Comment: It looks like you might be confused about how a string is _represented_ vs it's value.  Why are you "escaping" these strings like this to begin with?

Comment: slashes don't need to be escaped. What makes you think you need to escape them?

Comment: is it possible to evaluate it instead?  like: eval(url.replace('/','\\/') )

Comment: possible? Yes. Something you should do? No.

Comment: I need to return a value that will be parsed.  The validator needs this format: https:\/\/docs.python.org\/2\/reference\/expressions.html

Comment: That seems like a very, very odd requirement.  You're saying a validator explicitly requires invalid URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using repr() or eval() were throwing syntax errors when called within the dictionary.  The work around I found was to use the final dictionary when it returns the url and use the replace function outside the local dictionary instead of within.

Answer (score 0):

No it has to do with how you are displaying the data. The string contains what you expect. The problem is that you aren't printing the string, you are printing `repr(thestring)` which shows the literal string representation of it (i.e. how you'd type the string literal in your code) and therefore it includes escapes for the backslashes.